# Classes without constructor in F#

Tags: .net, f#

I'm not sure why F# seems to allow the definition of a class without any constructors.  I mean, it would be impossible to instantiate an object of the class.  Shouldn't the language spec treat this as illegal behavior?

For example, I can define the class

```
type myClass =
    class
        member this.x = 0
    end
```

`myClass` seems to have the type

```
type myClass =
    member x: int
```

But it would not be instantiable.

Comment: You could always inherit from it and use it like an interface.

Answer (score 9):

In my experience, the object-oriented features of F# can sometimes be less elegant than what C# enables you to express. The above question could be one example; another example is automatically implemented mutable properties.

Most people (including me) seem not to care, because we rarely use those features. The object-oriented features of F# mainly exist in order to enable interoperation with other .NET code, so while they can be useful, they aren't the *important* parts of the language. My guess is that no one thought of implementing that compiler check because it wouldn't provide much value. As soon as you'd attempt to use `myClass`, you'd notice that something was wrong.

Answer (score 3):

When you create a class with no constructors (in other words, a class that can't be instantiated) you are basically creating an static class*.

In C# you can use the `static` keyword to allow the compiler to check if you have instance members or not. In F# you don't have such check in compile time.

<sub>* Sort of. The proper definition of a static class is one that can't be instantiated or inherited and only has static methods.</sub>

Comment: To define a class that is represented as "static class" in the object browser, write `[<AbstractClass; Sealed>] type C = class end`. However, even in this case, F# currently allows you to add instance members to the class...

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but I'll add that sometimes, "a class that can't be instantiated" is exactly what you want for one reason or another. In my use case, by using a type that can't be instantiated, I can ensure that the only way to get a valid object of that type is within the scope of a lambda -- it's a way of implementing lambda type-checking in domain-specific languages.