# F#: difference between type defined with and without parenthesis

Tags: f#

What's the difference between `type Something()` and `type Something` in F#?

Why this snippet  referenced in [ASP.NET Core 1.0 F# project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38275408/asp-net-core-1-0-f-project) works:

```
open System
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http

type Startup() = 
    member this.Configure(app: IApplicationBuilder) =
      app.Run(fun context -> context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello from ASP.NET Core!"))

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let host = WebHostBuilder().UseKestrel().UseStartup<Startup>().Build()
    host.Run()
    printfn "Server finished!"
    0
```

but this fails:

```
open System
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http

type Startup = 
    member this.Configure(app: IApplicationBuilder) =
      app.Run(fun context -> context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello from ASP.NET Core!"))

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let host = WebHostBuilder().UseKestrel().UseStartup<Startup>().Build()
    host.Run()
    printfn "Server finished!"
    0
```

Comment: Different types are all defined via the `type` keyword in F#, including type aliases, DUs, records, classes, etc. The different arguments will indicate what kind of type you are creating. [Intro to F# types:](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/series/understanding-fsharp-types.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can see the difference by typing it in the F# Interactive:

```
type Parens() =
    member this.add10 x = x + 10

type NoParens =
    member this.add10 x = x + 10;;
```

Output:

```
type Parens =
  class
    new : unit -> Parens
    member add10 : x:int -> int
  end
type NoParens =
  class
    member add10 : x:int -> int
  end
```

The second class doesn't have a constructor defined. Something the compiler shouldn't allow, but does for some reason. It doesnt generate an automatic constructor like C#.

For more info check the *F# for fun and profit* pages on [classes](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/classes/) and [interfaces](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/interfaces/). Also check out this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33014900/classes-without-constructor-in-f)

And for future reference, when in doubt, open the F# interactive, type the two things you want to see the difference between, and compare the output. It is a powerful tool and you should use it.